# Zend filter int - why string first

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can anyone explain why `Zend_Filter_Int` casts the value to string first then int i.e.:

```
public function filter($value)
{
    return (int) ((string) $value);
}
```

I cant see any reason for this.

Comment: probably because php doesn't have a __toInt magic method for classes... but it does have a __toString ... basically as a means to cast it to a scalar value that can then be further coerced.

Comment: @Orangepill: Doesn't that make a huge assumption? That if an object were passed that it has a __toString method defined, if not a fatal occurs. If this were the case, they should at least check if __toString is callable before casting it.

Comment: with the alternative of everything failing with a fatal if it isn't castable as an int

Answer (score 0):

> Zend_Filter_Int allows you to transform a scalar value which contains
>   into an integer.

Casting the passed in value as a string simply enforces that a scalar value has been passed.

While I'm sure a debate of epic proportions may be had on what constitutes a scalar value. In this context anything that can be cast as a string is scalar. :)